# Unable to run asp file. Instead being prompted to download said asp file

Tags: html, asp-classic

Currently, I have my html code have a form that inputs a first and last name. I have set the input type as `submit` and set the `action` attribute as the asp file. However, when I click the submit button, my brower shows me a dialog box and asks if I wanted to download the said asp file.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="test1.asp" method="get">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Customer" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I've researched on the submit form but my form code looks almost exactly like the code on this website: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

I have also seen a question that is similar to the problem I am having:

[ASP : File download of ASP page comes instead of executing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735133/asp-file-download-of-asp-page-comes-instead-of-executing-it)

However, in that scenario, the asp file is being executed itself, while I am trying to execute the asp file through a html form.

As always, any and all help is grealty appreciated.

Comment: Does your web server have the approrpiate MIME handlers for ASP files? That's how your web server decided whether to execute something or serve it for download. If there is no handler for a file type, it will be sent as a download by default.

Comment: That may be the problem. I will check on that and get back to you.

Comment: I have tried adding the appropriate MIME handler. However, the problem still remains.

Comment: I think you need to make sure you did it correctly. As I said, that is what determines whether to send the file as a download, or to execute it. What server are you using?

Comment: IIS 7. As to what I did, I went into the server manager, went into MIME types, and noticed that the extension .asp was not listed. So I added in the .asp extension and I put text/asp as the MIME type.

Comment: You also need a handler mapping: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754147(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP is not Installed by default on IIS 7.0 and IIS 7.5, see [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis/) and [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/559/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis/) to see how to enable it if this is the case for you.

Copied from these links:

> In IIS 7.0 and 7.5, the classic version of ASP is not installed by default. Because of this, you might see HTTP 404 errors when you try to browse to an ASP page on your server, or you might see the source code for your ASP page displayed in your browser window. Both of these error conditions are created when configuration settings that are used to define the environment for classic ASP are not installed.

Hope this helps.