# How to run .asp files

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to learn basic ASP (not ASP.NET;although I don't know the difference) after learning HTML and VBScript.
I am running into problems when opening the files.
I am saving the file with .asp extension and trying to open it with Internet Explorer.
Given below are the codes and the file.
[image]

**But as soon as I try to open it, I get the following error.**

[image]

**What do I do to make it run?**

NB:I have seen the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159358/unable-to-run-asp-file-instead-being-prompted-to-download-said-asp-file) but I don't understand how to configure it myself.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not that it is any of my business but... any specific reason why you want to learn classic ASP? it is not the most friendly, broadly accepted, supported, modern, usable script language there is around...

Comment: I honestly don't know why it's still being taught to us but it is in my school syllabus.Anyway our teacher told us that it will be discontinued from the school curriculum next year onward. And there are no good resources on the internet to start learning from scratch so I'm in a  pickle. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'd have a web server that knows how to process a `.asp` file so that it executes the VBScript on the page. IIS and Apache would be examples of web server software where IIS is from Microsoft and likely can run the files without problems while Apache is more common for Java environments.

IIS is a feature within Windows that in the Professional versions can be installed through the Control Panel. The key is to enable the feature and make sure that the ASP box is also checked.

Comment: so will I have to download IIS?Any particular version ?

Comment: You install it as it usually is built into windows though there can be some configuration to do.

Comment: can you please help me with it or maybe provide me with a link?

Comment: If you have the Professional version of Windows you can activate IIS through Control Panel.  Here's a link for Win8, the procedure is the same in 7 http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-turn-on-iis-internet-information-services.  If you don't have a Pro edition you can download IIS Express